# Why there is only `HoldFirst` but no `HoldSecond`, `HoldThird`, ...`HoldN`?

Tags: function-construction, hold, attributes

I feel that this must be a duplicate. But I just can't find such a post.

Mathematica has `HoldFirst`, `HoldRest`, `HoldAll`.

Why are these three "Hold"s sufficient? Why there is no `HoldSecond`, `HoldThird`, ... `HoldN`?

What if I want to hold several variables at different positions? For example how can I hold first and third at the same time?

Comment: Would `HoldAll` give you unwanted consequences in the case you describe?

Comment: Duplicate is on SO: [Hold any argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7255999/5400699)

Comment: Any reason one couldn't do `f[heldStuff_List, notHeld1_,...]` with `HoldFirst`?

Comment: @N.J.Evans I drop a comment to m_goldberg, that also reply to your comment

Comment: @MarcoB thank you, you are right, `HoldAll` works for the function that I am currently working with.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for `HoldSecond`, etc., because arguments can always be reordered so the held argument is the first one. `HoldRest` is needed so an indefinite number of arguments can be passed, but the first argument subjected to pattern matching to discriminate which of many function definitions applies. `HoldAll` handles almost all other cases of non-standard evaluation, but see [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) and [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceHold.html).

The above may not be an exhaustive list of the reasons for these being the only holding patterns, but I believe it is sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: well, about reordering arguments, I have different opinion. I think we should order arguments in compliance with out logic, sometimes, reordering arguments makes me uncomfortable. :)

Comment: My last comment has a mistake, it should be "our logic" not "out logic". But I found that I can't modify the comment any more.